# Login Form and Protecting Pages only for Logged in Users?

Tags: php, html

I’ve created a login form in PHP that works ok, but I’ve realised my page my user is directed too can still be accessed by anybody. How do I go on protecting the pages for it to be only accessible only by those who are logged into the site?

Do I need to place a script on the success page itself?

I’ve tried quite a few different things, but not sure what is going on. Here is what I have so far!

checking_login.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
$host=""; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name=""; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['password'] = $mypassword;
header("location: portkey.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password. ";
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Here is the page part of where I was talking about redirecting the page too. (Its still public to everyone).

```
<?php
session_start();
$host=""; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername'])) {
        header("location:login.php");
    }
?>
```

Login is the page with the form. The table/users.

```
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="checking.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="0">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: remove the second call to `session_start()` in your protected page

Comment: you're not intending on going live with this, are you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if `username` isset:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        header("location:login.php");
    }
```

Also, you are calling `session_start();` twice. The second call will however be ignored.

*Tip*: Instead of storing the username and password, you should be storing the user `id` in the session.

Answer (score 0):

You don't start the session on `checking_login.php`. Change your code to:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['password'] = $mypassword;
```

You don't need to start the session twice on the protected page. Remove the `session_start();` above the `if` statement.

In addition... on your protected page, you're checking for a session that **doesn't exist!** Change `if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername'])) {` to `if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {`

Answer (score 0):

The reason your members-only page is still visible and accessible by anyone is, because you have not correctly checked, if there is a `user session` set.

To make your code work, you need to change you conditional statement from:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername'])) {
    header("location:login.php");
}
```

to:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("location: login.php");
}
```

because `myusername` is is not the variable you stored into your session.

Quoting your setting of the `$_SESSION`:

> $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;

When you set your `$_SESSION` you used `username` and not `myusername`. Be sure to stick to that when checking if `$_SESSION` is set.

In order for your page to work as you desire you must use the following format:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <?php
            // Check if user session is set. If it is redirect to login.php.
            if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])):
                header("location: login.php");

            // If it is not set show the your login form.
            else:
        ?>

        <!--Your HTML code for the form.-->

        <?php
            endif;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

In case your login form is in another page, then you can redirect again by changing the `else` part as shown:

```
// If it is not set show the your login form.
else:
    header("location: loginform.php"); // The name of the file
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a global `header.php` file, then in that check if the `$_SESSION['username']` is set. If it is, set `$logged_in = true`, and if it's not, set `$logged_in = false`. It's what I use for my website. If you don't use `header.php`, then in the page check for `$_SESSION['username']`. For both, if `$looged_in = true` or `isset($_SESSION['username'])`, then DON'T redirect. but if `$logged_in = false` or `!isset($_SESSION['username'])` then you redirect them. You could also set a `$_SESSION['logged_in']` variable.

some code to help.

```
header('location: page.php'); // REDIRECT VIA PHP

// IF YOU HAVE header.php
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) $logged_in = true; // IN herder.php
else $logged_in = false; // IN herder.php

if($logged_in != true) header('location: login.php') // IN USERS ONLY PAGE

// IF YOU DON'T HAVE header.php

// OPTION 1
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) header('location: login.php'); // IN USERS ONLY PAGE

// OPTION 2
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true; // WHEN THE USER HAS LOGGED IN

if($_SESSION['logged_in'] != true) header('location: login.php'); // IN USERS ONLY PAGE
```